# How should I count the number of operations in my algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

After searching web, I found following solution for step count method.

```
int mean(int a[], size_t n)
{
    int sum = 0;                 // 1 step * 1
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  // 1 step * (N+1)
        sum += a[i];             // 1 step * N
    return sum;                  // 1 step * 1
}
```

Hence, the step count is 2N+3.

However, in a YouTube video, I saw that, for the same situation, they obtained a count of 6N+4. In that video, they count assignment, addition operations as steps.

Which is the correct method? The Big-O value remains the same, but, if someone ask me to give them a step count for the algorithm, what should I answer?

Comment: There is no correct answer. It depends on how you define what a "step" is, and different people will define it differently.

Comment: There really isn't a good answer unless you know the instruction set of the processor you're running on to make it concrete, otherwise it's just instinct. It doesn't matter a lot in the end, since coefficients and lower-order terms are going to be ignored anyway, partly because of this.

Comment: @interjay Just created a paradox by giving you the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is the correct method? Big O value is same. But if someone ask to give step count for the algorithm how do I answer?

It's a matter of convention:

- some people count additions and multiplications together,
- others just multiplications, because they would typically be more demanding operations than additions (although that's less true on modern architectures), and
- yet other keep separate counts of additions and multiplications,
- etc.

As long as you're crystal-clear as to which convention you're adopting, anything goes. The choice of convention has typically no impact on the *asymptotics* (the "Big-O value") anyway , although it would affect the *constant factors*.

**Edit**: As pointed out by dwn in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668873/step-count-of-an-algorithm/27668910#comment43752600_27668910), what goes on "close to the metal" may end up having a different algorithmic complexity to that of your source code, because of compiler/interpreter optimization tricks.

Comment: Yes, and what is shown in the code is not necessarily what is happening in the processor anyway. BigO doesn't care about our puny steps.

Comment: Ok got it. If there is a global variable as in below code is it count as step?  int count = 0; //global variable
int sum(int a[], int n)
{ //return sum of "n" integers in array "a"
int s = 0;
count++; //for int s = 0; declaration
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
count++; //for loop expression evaluation
s += a[i];
count++; //for s += a[i]; assignment
}
count++; //for last evaluation of loop expression
count++; //for return statement
return s;
}

Comment: @cmit Are you asking whether variable declarations/assignments should be counted to?

Comment: Declarations, no, assigments, possibly (probably).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you count there but, if you count the primitive operations involved then the calculation is a bit different.

The `for()` line contains the following operations:

- `i = 0` - 1 operation;
- `i < n` - 1 operation, `N` times;
- `i ++` - 2 operations, `N` times; `i ++` is a shortcut for `i = i + 1` and this involves an addition and an assignment, therefore 2 operations;

Next, `sum += a[i]` is a shortcut for `sum = sum + a[i]` and that contains the computation of address of `a[i]` which is an addition (1 operation), the addition (`sum + a[i]`) and the assignment (2 operations). And all these happen `N` times;

Summing all up there are `6 * N + 2` operations but, as other posters noticed, it depends a lot of what you count. If you analyze the assembler code generated by the compiler for this source code you'll notice there are also read instructions and they should be counted too.

All in all, the algorithm is linear, its complexity is `O(n)` and this is the most important fact about it. This notation washes out the `4` or `6` or whatever value one puts in front of `N` because it is irrelevant.